# Is it possible to make a form invisible and not the buttons? VB

Tags: vb.net, forms

For example, I know how to make the form completely invisible but the buttons also get invisible. Any way where I can make the button visible but the form invisible? Other word I want an image button without the form in the backgroud. Thanks

-Safoku

Comment: Yes, for what platform: winforms, WPF?

Comment: Search for "shaped window" and "transparent window".

Comment: Here are a bunch of varied related tasks (albeit for C# and likely WinForms, I didn't follow through reading) - http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form1.htm

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set the background color to the transparency key:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    Me.BackColor = Color.Magenta
    Me.TransparencyKey = Color.Magenta
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that as close to it as I got. Now when I add an image to it what happen is the button is stil visibe. Where I only want the image visible

Comment: @Safoku Set the button color to the transparency color.

Comment: Or just set the button Visible property to False.

Comment: If I set the button to invisible wont the image also be invisible?